# Questions about device drivers: Where would this even be on-topic?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have several questions about how device drivers interact with modern PC hardware. However, I have *no idea* where such questions would actually be on-topic.

- Since I'm not trying to actually *write* a device driver, this seems off-topic for Stack Overflow.
- I'm not asking about software design methodologies, so Software Engineering also seems off-topic.
- I'm not trying to *build* any hardware, so this seems off-topic for Electronics.
- Questions like this get asked and answered all the time on Retrocomputing. But since I'm asking about *modern* hardware, this is clearly off-topic there too.
- This is about specific real-world hardware, not theoretical devices, so Computer Science appears off-topic too.
- I'm not trying to solve a practical IT problem, so definitely off-topic for Server Fault.
- This isn't even a practical end-user problem, so doesn't fit Superuser.
- It's nothing to do with Unix, so clearly off-topic for Linux & Unix.

...I have no idea where else to ask. Suggestions?

I'm pretty damned sure there are people on the SE network who know the answers I want, but I have no idea where such questions would be permissible.

**Edit:** Some examples of the questions I'm thinking about asking:

- How does keyboard input work on a PC? Does the CPU poll the keyboard to see what keys are currently pressed, or does pressing a key generate a hardware interrupt, or...?
- Is the PCI communication protocol implemented in hardware or software? (I.e., does the CPU have to explicitly construct a command package and send it, or does the PCI bus controller do that for you?)
- Is the framebuffer of the graphics card ever mapped into the address space of the CPU? Or does the CPU have to explicitly construct a command packet and have that sent to the GPU to tell it to draw something?

Comment: Can you include a (small) gist of one such question you want to ask? So we can follow along your reasoning with that example question in mind.

Comment: [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) says "Questions about how a particular piece of software or hardware works aren't science (unless you're asking about the scientific concepts behind that software or hardware)." I don't have enough experience with them to tell if "How does the driver code interact with the hardware"  counts as the science in their eyes though.

Comment: @rene Well, like, is the framebuffer of my graphics card mapped into the address space of my CPU, or do I have to send commands to the GPU to make it draw stuff. That kind of thing.

Comment: This is [SU] type stuff, unless you’re actually writing the drivers, in which case it is fair game for [SO] (although you must be *very* careful to avoid making the question too broad to be reasonably answered in our format—one could write, and indeed many have written, a long-form book about the mechanics of display drivers). Also beware that there won’t be one single answer unless you narrow to a specific OS and hardware product.

Comment: @CodyGray Is that an answer rather than a comment?

Comment: I searched for those questions and found this for the last one on [su]: [How does the CPU and GPU interact in displaying computer graphics?](https://superuser.com/questions/461022/how-does-the-cpu-and-gpu-interact-in-displaying-computer-graphics) Seems to have been well received.

Comment: All those questions are too broad for SO. I suggest you to find appropriate books and just read them first, e.g. "How to make keyboard driver" (I am sure you will find all answers regarding keyboard input there). Then your questions (if any) become much more narrow. Now you are in situation like many of those new posters: they know nothing, they cba to read anything, they just want their things done, so they ask their questions. But it's too early to ask yet.

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid `Is that an answer rather than a comment?` Would that make the information given any more valuable for you?

Comment: Your first example question has been asked here before, probably more than once.  (The answer is that it depends on how the keyboard is connected.  USB keyboards are polled, PS/2 keyboards are interrupt driven.) I've seen questions like your third here before. (The answer is both.)

Comment: Typically what users should do when faced with this sort of question is to go to [meta.se], explain the problem, include the actual question you want to ask in a blockquote, and ask for advice on where to ask it. [meta.se] is the overall meta site, and is frequented by people from all over the [se] network of sites, and generally advice is offered pretty quickly.

Comment: @Xatenev Answers should go in the answer box, not the comment box.